# Unable to boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, grub-efi

I initially had Windows 10 in my laptop and decided to dual boot it with Ubuntu. I successfully installed Ubuntu 20.04, but now my laptop is automatically loading Ubuntu only. No GRUB menu is shown and no option for choosing Windows is given.

[Boot repair info summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dwZg5TrGh9/)

I did the same steps given in boot-repair site and it showed successful boot repair too, but nothing changed, still no GRUB menu.

What else can I try to fix this?

Comment: Grub does not show when you only have Ubuntu installed. You show no evidence of even having Windows. No NTFS partitions, no UEFI boot entry, nothing. The UEFI boot entry is not normally erased during Ubuntu install, but your install selections could erase NTFS partitions. You do have good backup of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Often Ubuntu will not show GRUB by default, but you can learn how here: [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

If you do not see Windows, try running `sudo update-grub` in the terminal, and the booting back into GRUB.

Comment: When I press ESC key, it now shows grub menu. But there are only 3 options shown: Ubuntu,Advanced Options for Ubuntu ,UEFI firmware settings.  There is no option for Windows .What to do now?

Comment: What options do you get under UEFI firmware settings?

Comment: When I choose UEFI firmware settings,it goes back to startup menu with all the keys like f9,f10 etc.

Comment: And the startup menu does not offer another option along the lines of "boot manager" or "select boot device" that you have not yet tried?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include this, but try running sudo update-grub and then check if you can see Windows then.

Comment: I've tried that too,but no change.When i click UEFI firmware settings,it goes back to startup menu and i clicked on boot device options.In that it shows Ubuntu,Notebook,and NO VOLUME LABEL.I have no idea what to do.Is this happening because of some mistakes I made during manual disk partitioning?

Comment: Just look into this image.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uYay6Jb-WHXLJy2AQO03ICd7pa7KcMfj/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Naina You say you did manual disk partitioning?   What partitions did you specify?

Comment: Have you tried booting into Notebook and NO VOLUME LABEL?

Answer (score 0):

"boot repairs" are neither Microsoft or Ubuntu to be thought 100% effective or safe.

Consequently--(i)why not re-install both systems --if you have the discs?

Reason :-- Windows 10 should reinstall without any difficulty --

c/f 20.04 --is still not the official and tested safe release:

"Note that the recommended upgrade process currently displays the announcement of the development release, which is causing some confusion about whether 20.04 LTS is actually on-topic yet. – ændrük Apr 25 at 16:00 "

"Beware of the development release, my system had trouble to start after upgrade today. Cursor could move but system did not react to any action. Please also create an appropriate tag for Ubuntu 20.4 "– iArnold Apr 28 at 21:05 etc

hope not confusing.